# how can I find out bits per pixel using into my framebuffer?

Tags: graphics, xorg

I know the X.org server run is executed with certain value of bpp, 8bpp by default i think.

But how can I find out the actual bits per pixel using into my framebuffer while i'm on linux? is there any command that can get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a terminal, run the `xwininfo` command, then choose a window - the `Depth:` result is the bits per pixel. For example:

```
$ xwininfo

xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.

xwininfo: Window id: 0x3e00005 "davidp@sysadmin: ~"

  Absolute upper-left X:  1920
  Absolute upper-left Y:  24
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 1920
  Height: 1056
  Depth: 32
  Visual: 0x74
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x3e00004 (not installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +1920+24  -0+24  -0-0  +1920-0
  -geometry 212x56-0-0
```

You could also use `xdpyinfo`, which will give you more information than you probably want - including all available bit depths for your displays (without showing you which one is actually in use).

Comment: I see 32 bits for the terminal window but 24 for the firefox browser window. So, actually, is it using different bpp in each window?

Comment: Yes, in X windows each window can choose the bit depth to use from the list of available bit depths.

Answer (score 2):

adding an answer since I lack reputation to post a comment to David Purdue's answer..

As David mentions, `xdpyinfo` can be used. The advantage over `xwininfo` is that you don't need to select a window, which can be handy when you are checking a virtual framebuffer created with `Xvfb`.

Here is a snippet of the relevant output of the command `xdpyinfo`:

```
....
screen #0:
  dimensions:    1024x768 pixels (260x195 millimeters)
  resolution:    100x100 dots per inch
  depths (6):    8, 1, 4, 16, 24, 32
  root window id:    0x4d
  depth of root window:    8 planes
  number of colormaps:    minimum 1, maximum 1
  default colormap:    0x20
....
```

The `depth of root window` reflects the bit depth of the root window, in this example it's 8 bits.

The `depths` property lists the supported bit depths, the first number indicates the current bit depth.